# Публикация docker контейнера в raspberry pi из visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, docker, core

Создал web api проект в Visual Studio 2019, разместил его в локальном контейнере (windowds 10). Хочу перенести его на raspberry pi. Копирую сам контейнер так: 
 1. docker save weathervikadata -o vika.tar 
 2. копирую на малинку 
 3. Развертываю `docker load -i vika.tar` 
   в списке есть `docker images`:
    weathervikadata     latest              22854ed37163        8 hours ago         214MB

4. Пытаюсь запустить `docker run -i -t 005e2b7a1551 /bin/bash`
   Происходит ошибка:

   standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
   failed to resize tty, using default size

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1):

На 10.04.2020 Поддержка ARM64 в Windows еще недоступна.
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0

Надо собирать образ на самой малинке.